# Unable to parse JSON from link - no errors, but the function returns after trying to access the URL

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am new to Swift and trying basic JSON parsing by following tutorials. I want to print a field of a JSON file, but it is not working.

Although the link exists, and I am using the same link I used for a previous tutorial, it returns rather than moved on to accessing the JSON.

I understand there is an "easier" way to do it in Swift4 using Decoder, but I received an error when I did it that way.

Here is the structure I am using:

```
struct Tester {
        var userId: Int
        var id: Int
        var title: String
        var body: String

        init(json: [String: Any]){
            userId = json["userId"] as? Int ?? -10
            id = json["id"] as? Int ?? -400
            title = json["title"] as? String ?? ""
            body = json["body"] as? String ?? ""
        }
    }
```

And here is the code that is trying to access the JSON entries

```
 @IBAction func printIDTitle(_ sender: Any) {


        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else { return }

        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }




            do {


                print("here 0\n")
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                print("here 0.5\n")
                print("here 1\n")
                let d = Tester(json: json)
                print(d.id)
                print(d.title)
                print("here 2\n")
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()






    }
```

The "here 0" is the only print that shows up.
What could be my issue?

Comment: Note that your tutorial is kind of out of date. `JSONSerialization` is still supported, but has largely been replaced by `JSONDecoder` and `JSONEncoder` (the workhorse methods for the new `Codable` protocol.)

Comment: Alright, I will keep that in mind, thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a tutorial on Codable. It's both much easier and more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

The root is an array so change

```
 guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [[String: Any]] else {
     print(error)
     return
  }
```

Or better

```
 let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from:data)


struct Root: Codable {
    let userId, id: Int
    let title, body: String 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!

When I try the first thing, I get the error:
`Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'`
on the `let d = Tester(json: json)` line.

I will see if I can try the second method!

Comment: change `init(json: [[String: Any])]{` now json is an array change everything according to that or better use option 2

Comment: The second one is _definitely_ the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am having trouble implementing the second way of doing it.

When I try `print(res.userID)` I get an error that says `Value of type '[ViewController.Root]' has no member 'userID'`

Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: it should be `print(res.first?.userID)` or `res.forEach { print($0.userID)}`

Comment: Thank you so much! It is printing now, but when I try to print the first thing, it has something that says `Optional([insert userID here])` around it

Comment: try `if let value = res.first?.userID { print(value) }`